# Yii: Display database values on one side of list builder

Tags: php, yii, widget

I have a list builder widget like [this](http://www.eha.ee/labs/yiiplay/index.php/en/site/extension?view=listbuilder)

This widget is working fine. When I store few selected values to database, I want those values to be displayed on the left side of the widget. I have tried fetching the values from DB and unable to move further with it.

```
$user = yii::app()->user->name;
$q = "select cmail from tbl_list where ename='$ename' and uname='$user'";
$res = Yii::app()->db
->createCommand($q)
->queryAll();      
foreach($res as $contactmail)
{
  select_left = $res; //select_left is the id of the left side of builder.
}
```

Comment: I think there is a big lack of knowledge. Is `select_left` a constant? If not, where is the `$` sign? And why do you save `$res` to `select_left` in your foreach and not `$contactmail`? Beside this question, it would make no sense, as long as `$res` has really only one result. But then you would not need a foreach loop.

Comment: select_left is not a constant, it is the 'id' of the left side. Moreover, I am sure that rest of the code is perfect except that statement.

Comment: Okay, please explain me the reason of your perfect code `select_left = $res;` - why do you put it into a foreach loop?